# Redis inside Docker Compose Permission Denied for RDB file Crontab

Tags: docker-compose, redis, aws-ec2

Hi I have following docker-compose.yaml file.

```
version: "3.9"

volumes:
  local_postgres_data2: {}
  local_postgres_data_backups2: {}

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    container_name: angel-postgres
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - local_postgres_data2:/var/lib/postgresql/data:Z
      - local_postgres_data_backups2:/backups:z
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: angel-agility
      POSTGRES_HOST: localhost
      POSTGRES_USER: angel-user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: angel123
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  redis:
    container_name: angel-redis
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    restart: unless-stopped
```

When I run docker-compose up I get error in logs for Redis:

```
2276:C 29 Mar 2022 20:32:52.005 # Failed opening the RDB file crontab (in server root dir /etc) for saving: Permission denied
1:M 29 Mar 2022 20:32:52.105 # Background saving error
```

I tried all the solutions on different platforms but couldn't make Redis work. A clue or direction make it work will be highly appreciated.

Also a little brief about the problem in detail why its happening would also be great help for readers and me. Looking forward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've encountered the same issue running a redis container on AWS ECS in a similar fashion.

I connected to the redis container and executed:

```
redis-cli
> CONFIG GET dbfilename
```

It returned the following:

```
1) "dbfilename"
2) "crontab"
```

I tried to remove the crontab file by running `config set dbfilename "dbfilename"` which failed with an error.

I've found out that redis was running **without** a config file. So I added an extra volume for redis and created the file using `touch data/redis/config/redis.conf`.

Then I've changed my compose file accordingly:

```
  redis:
    container_name: redis
    command: redis-server /conf/redis.conf
    image: redis:latest
    volumes:
       - "./data/redis/data:/data"
       - "./data/redis/config:/conf"
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    restart: unless-stopped
```

After rebooting the container I've run the same `CONFIG GET dbfilename` command but this time the crontab file was missing.

Everything worked after that :)

[image: Redis Config]

Also make sure that you set a password for your redis server if it's accessible from the internet.

```
    docker run -d \
    -h redis \
    -e REDIS_PASSWORD=your-super-secure-password \
    -v redis-data:/data \
    -v redis-config:/conf \
    -p 6379:6379 \
    --name redis \
    --restart always \
    redis:latest /bin/sh -c 'redis-server /conf/redis.conf --appendonly yes --requirepass ${REDIS_PASSWORD}'
```

Comment: With some experience over the years I just found out that what I was doing wrong was trying to run Redis while connecting to its port. Kind of solved issues a dozen time not only with Redis but a lot of different server tools.